# Facebook "create_events" in version v. 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-permissions

I'm new in this forum and I hope I'm doing everything right.

This is my problem:

I want to create a Facebook's event from my web site and I need the permission. In the first version of Facebook Developer we can simply add the extended permission `crate_events`, but this no longer exists in v.2.0. Do you know if there is a way to use it? Is it encapsulated in another permission?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the permission `create_events` no longer exists.

If you check the [Platform Change Log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), it clearly says-

> Apps can **no longer** create events with the API.

Comment: When do people start to believe in documentation... :-/